# Dynamically checking tuple length in mypy

Tags: python, tuples, mypy

I have program using a union of different-length tuple types, and it dynamically checks the length of tuples to refine the type.  Mypy does not recognize that a variable's type is more precisely known after this kind of dynamic check, so it reports spurious type errors.  How can I dynamically check tuple length in a way that mypy understands?

In the following example, mypy reports an error when `shape` is used as a tuple of two values, even though the assertion on the previous line ensures that its type is `Tuple[int, int]`.

```
from typing import *

def f(dimensions: int,
      shape: Union[Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int, int, int]]):
    if dimensions == 2:
        assert len(shape) == 2
        height, width = shape
        print(height * width)
```

Mypy reports an error on the tuple unpacking line: `error: Too many values to unpack (2 expected, 3 provided)`.

I am using mypy 0.720 with Python 3.7.4.

Comment: Why are you passing `dimensions` as a separate parameter rather than just using `len(shape)` directly?

Comment: I think that this suggestion would give better python code but I don't think it would solve the `mypy` problem.

Comment: No direct support: [python/mypy#1178](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1178), which recommends [`cast`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/casts.html) as a workaround.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The example is reduced from a larger program, where `dimensions` and `shape` are present in different data structures because other code needed them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an explicit [cast](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/casts.html) (see also [this issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1178) courtesy [@aaron's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8601760/aaron) comment):

```
if dimensions == 2:
    assert len(shape) == 2
    shape = cast(Tuple[int, int], shape)
    height, width = shape
    print(height * width)
```

Also, as pointed out in other answers, the `dimension` argument is superfluous and you could just do

```
def f2(shape: Union[Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int, int, int]]):
    dimensions: int = len(shape)
    if dimensions == 2:
        shape = cast(Tuple[int, int], shape)
        height, width = shape
        print(height * width)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume this will happen if you are passing dimensions as 2, but passing a tuple containing 3 ints. Is this the case?

Pretty sure you could use:

```
dimensions = len(shape)
```

at the top of your function to get the actual number of entries in the passed tuple rather than needing to pass in a (potentially wrong) dimension parameter.

This would seem to be a general python issue, and not anything to do with mypy, but I could well be wrong and have missed something important :)

Also, if you want to support tuples of any length in your function, I believe you can use the type Tuple[int, ...] to support a tuple with any number if ints, instead of using the union if you so wanted.

Comment: I think that this suggestion would give better python code but I don't think it would solve the mypy problem.

Comment: @Dave_Birch This example is reduced from a larger program, and the variables `dimension` and `shape` already exist for other reasons in the original program.  They aren't directly passed as function parameters.